Fantasy/action movie with double worlds/shadow worlds
Sadly I only watched the trailer for the movie, but I will try to give as much information as possible:

Debut performance was mostly like (99%!) within the last 3 years.
A girl is the main actor of the movie.
The movie seems to have two worlds, one of the normal humans and one of shadow creatures? Not sure about the last one, but there are two co-existing worlds if I understood right.
In the trailer she sees a murder happening (maybe behind a mirror?) while she is out in the club partying, but no one except her sees it.
If I remember right she was something like a doppelganger, who can walk and be seen/take action in both worlds.
Later in the trailer she's becoming friends with some guys from the "shadow" world.
Seemed to be a Hollywood production...
It was not animated.

Sadly this is all I remember.
I already tried different movie channels on YouTube to find the trailer, but always failed...

Sounds like The Mortal Instruments: City of Bones from 2013 with Lily Collins.

Set in contemporary New York City, a seemingly ordinary teenager, Clary Fray, discovers she is the descendant of a line of Shadowhunters, a secret cadre of young half-angel warriors locked in an ancient battle to protect our world from demons. After the disappearance of her mother, Clary must join forces with a group of Shadowhunters, who introduce her to a dangerous alternate New York called Downworld, filled with demons, warlocks, vampires, werewolves and other deadly creatures. 

She's the only one who sees a murder being committed in a nightclub in the beginning. It was based on the first novel in a series by Cassandra Clare. Here's the trailer:




Yes! That's it! Thanks a lot. Now that I know the title I know why my google searches didn't find anything ...
Perfect answer, 10/10. Will be accepted when the time is over ...
